# Arguments.callee is deprecated - what should be used instead?

Tags: javascript, cross-browser

For doing things like

```
setTimeout(function () {
    ...
    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 100);
}, 100);
```

I need something like `arguments.callee`. I found [information at javascript.info](http://javascript.info/tutorial/arguments#arguments-callee) that `arguments.callee` is deprecated:

> **This property is deprecated** by ECMA-262 in favor of named function
>   expressions and for better performance.

**But what should be then used instead?** Something like this?

```
setTimeout(function myhandler() {
    ...
    setTimeout(myhandler, 100);
}, 100);
// has a big advantage that myhandler cannot be seen here!!! 
// so it doesn't spoil namespace
```

BTW, is `arguments.callee` cross-browser compatible?

Comment: For what it's worth: [Named function expressions demystified](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/).

Comment: Yes, you should name your function and use its name in setTimeout.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why was the arguments.callee.caller property deprecated in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/103598/why-was-the-arguments-callee-caller-property-deprecated-in-javascript)

Comment: @cHao, nope, that's not a duplicate: arguments.callee.caller deprecation **doesn't imply deprecation of the whole arguments.callee**. Moreover, this question doesn't ask **"what should be used instead!"**

Comment: @Tomas: Check the answers.  Everything you've asked is mentioned within them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, that's what, theoretically, *should* be used. You're right. However, it doesn't work in some versions of Internet Explorer, as always. So be careful. You may need to fall back on `arguments.callee`, or, rather, a simple:

```
function callback() {
    // ...
    setTimeout(callback, 100);
}

setTimeout(callback, 100);
```

Which does work on IE.

Comment: Wait - you want to say that `setTimeout(function myhandler() { setTimeout(myhandler ...` will not work in some versions of IE? Is this a non-standard thing? I thought it is a pretty standard thing to do.

Comment: @TomasT.: It *is* standard - but since when has IE ever been completely standard? :) (Well, maybe IE10.) I remember being tripped up by it some time. A quick test reveals that it's not an issue in IE7 at least. Probably IE6. I don't have it with me to test.

Comment: According to Microsoft, it works in IE6: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/callee-property-arguments-javascript

Comment: @lolzerywowzery: That’s `arguments.callee`, not named function expressions. There are three periods of named function expressions in IE, IIRC: not working at all, leaking into the surrounding scope, and working according to spec.

Answer (score 5):

> **But what should be then used instead?** Something like this?

Yes, you answered your own question. For more information, see here:

[Why was the arguments.callee.caller property deprecated in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103598/why-was-the-arguments-callee-caller-property-deprecated-in-javascript)

It has a pretty good discussion about why this change was made.

Answer (score 1):

minitech answer is quite good, but it is missing one more scenario. Your declare function called callback, which means two things, first the function is object in memory, and the second, the function name is only for referencing to the object. If you, for any reason break the reference between these two, the proposed code will not work too.

Proof:

```
function callback() {
    // ...
    setTimeout(callback, 100);
}

setTimeout(callback, 100);

var callback2 = callback; //another reference to the same object
callback = null; //break the first reference
callback2(); //callback in setTimeout now is null.
```

From [developer Mozilla page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee) in the description is:

> Warning: The 5th edition of ECMAScript (ES5) forbids use of
>   arguments.callee() in strict mode. Avoid using arguments.callee() by
>   either giving function expressions a name or use a function
>   declaration where a function must call itself.

obviously this is the first example of workaround "*by either giving function expressions a name*", but lets see how we can deal with "*or use a function declaration where a function must call itself*" and what will that bring:

```
function callback(){
   //...
   setTimeout(innercall(), 100);
   function innercall(){
      //innercall is safe to use in callback context
      innercall.caller(); //this will call callback();
   }
}
```

Then we are safe to do whatever we want with the callback reference:

```
var callback2 = callback;
callback = null;
callback2(); //will work perfectly.
```

Comment: `caller` isn’t good practice, and the sample code here doesn’t actually seem to set a timeout. Just don’t overwrite your declared function.