# arguments.callee alternative

Tags: javascript

As `arguments.callee` is going to be deprecated, what would I use of instead of arguments.callee` in the following expression:

```
var self = this;

this.async(function(){
  if(test()){
    then();
  }else{
    self.async(arguments.callee);
  }
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Arguments.callee is deprecated - what should be used instead?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361642/arguments-callee-is-deprecated-what-should-be-used-instead)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work. But i'm not sure if it works in all browsers.

```
var self = this;

this.async(function someMethod(){
  if(test()){
    then();
  }else{
    self.async(someMethod);
  }
});
```

Comment: The famous [Kangax article](http://kangax.github.com/nfe/) details the bugs/quirks, but generally it'll still work.