# Submit hidden form after a delay, or immediately if a link is clicked

Tags: javascript, progressive-enhancement

My application's session management will redirect a user to a page where the user is told their session has timed out and please `<a href="path/to/page.html" id="manual_link">sign in</a>`.

I'm trying to program the following behavior:

1. If JavaScript is *off* (or otherwise not available), the user will have to click on the "sign in" link (POHTML; no problem).
2. If JavaScript is *running*:

   a). progressively-enhance the link to instead submit the hidden form with an id of "security_redirect" (`document.getElementById('manual_link').onclick = "javascript:submit_security_redirect(); return false;";`)

   b) if the user does not click the link first, auto-submit the form after a 4 second delay (assume `remaining_time` to be 4000):

   ```
       setTimeout(function () {
           submit_security_redirect();
       }, remaining_time);
   ```

The four-second-delay-then-submit is happening, but I can't seem to get the link to intercept if the user doesn't want to wait four seconds. In other words, if the user clicks the link after one second...nothing happens until the four seconds are up.

I suspect I need to kill the setTimeout on link click, but don't know how (my fumbling attempts at [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout#Example) were so disappointing I don't even include them in [the example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhfrench/7R73f/)). And/or I need to prevent the `a`'s default behavior (though I thought `return false` squares that away).

**What modifications are necessary to achieve the desired functionality?**

Comment: What does `submit_security_redirect()` do?

Comment: `submit_security_redirect()` is the function that actually submits the form; this part is working. In the fiddle it calls an `alert('fire submit');`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't set `onclick` like that in the same way that you would set the `onclick` attribute in HTML -- you need to set it to a function, e.g.:

```
document.getElementById('manual_link').onclick = function() {
    submit_security_redirect(); return false;
};
```

When adding event handlers via Javascript, calling `addEventListener` is actually better than setting `onclick`, but unfortunately doesn't work in IE versions 8 and below, which is one of the reasons why cross-platform libraries like jQuery are great for event handling.

BTW, arguments.callee is deprecated (see [Arguments.callee is deprecated - what should be used instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361642/arguments-callee-is-deprecated-what-should-be-used-instead)).

Comment: IE9+ supports `addEventListener`; as an alternative `attachEvent`.  If you use the event calling mechanism, `event.preventDefault` should be used.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out...I updated my answer to say IE "versions 8 and below".

Comment: Aaaaaaaaahhhh. <homer voice>stupid computer syntax</homer voice>

Comment: If I go the jQuery route, I'd probably have the PE swap out the link for a submit button styled (via Bootstrap) as a link. Then I wouldn't have to set the `onclick` or `.click()` because I could just use the submit's native behavior. I'm trying to keep the page weight down, for some reason (especially weird since I'm loading jQuery via CDN). I should rethink that...

Comment: Whether you use jQuery's `click()` on a link or a regular form submit button is likely to make very little practical difference in terms of page load time.

Comment: Glanced at this again, and noticed something else: `javascript:` shouldn't even be used in an HTML `onclick` attribute...you only need to prefix the JS with `javascript:` for the `href` of `<a>` tags.