# Alternative to arguments.callee

Tags: javascript, reflection, arguments, deprecated, porting

I have an *EventListener* that listens to the entire document and records keystrokes, but I want to remove this Listener when certain conditions are met.

The following is a snippet of my code:

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
    var letter_entered = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).toLowerCase();
    player.makeGuess(letter_entered);

    if(player.win_status === true || player.lose_status === true) {
        document.removeEventListener('keyup', arguments.callee, false);
    }
});
```

This works, however according to the [Mozilla Developer Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee) this method has been deprecated.

I'm aware that I can simply name the function, but **is there an alternative that would allow me to continue using the unnamed function**?

Comment: No. You have to store a reference to it somehow, like `arguments.callee` does.

Comment: Why would you insist on using an unnamed function?

Comment: @user2736012 Question is more out of curiosity than practical use.

Comment: No, there's no other way other than to use a variable reference to an anonymous function. If there was, it would just be redundant.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Arguments.callee is deprecated - what should be used instead?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361642/arguments-callee-is-deprecated-what-should-be-used-instead)

Answer (score 16):

Use the following process:

- Create a variable
- Assign an anonymous function to the variable
- Invoke it with the variable reference
- The anonymous function references itself using the variable name

Use it as such:

```
   var foo = function(e)
    {
    "use strict";
    console.log(e);
    document.removeEventListener('keyup', foo, false);
    }

document.addEventListener('keyup', foo);
```

You can solve this problem easily using the `y` combinator:

```
function y(f) {
    return function () {
        return f.bind(null, y(f)).apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
```

Now you can rewrite your code as follows:

```
document.addEventListener("keyup", y(function (callee, e) {
    player.makeGuess(String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).toLowerCase());
    if (player.win_status || player.lose_status) document
        .removeEventListener("keyup", callee);
}));
```

That's all folks.

Comment: Is this different from `function y(f) { return function yf() { return f.bind(null, yf).apply(this, arguments)`?

Comment: Yes, but the entire point of the OP's question is not to use named functions.

Comment: Cool stuff but it doesn't answer the question which is in the title. In fairness, the title is wrong.  :)  But I was actually looking for the answer to a generic alternative for `arguments.callee` and this isn't it.

Comment: Javascript is such a weird language, thanks for this solution! I didn't know it was possible to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Use another anonymous function as a wrapper to store a named function (callee shim) to your original function:

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', (function(e)
  {
  var aFunction = function()
    {
    var letter_entered = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode).toLowerCase();
    player.makeGuess(letter_entered);
    };

  if(player.win_status === true || player.lose_status === true) 
    {
    document.removeEventListener('keyup', window, false);
    }
  else
    {
    aFunction();
    }
  }
), false);
```

**References**

- [Strict Mode is Coming to Town](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/12/14/strict-mode-is-coming-to-town/)
- [ES3.1:arguments.callee](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=es3.1:arguments.callee)
- [Recursion with anonymous (inline) functions in XPath 3.0](https://dnovatchev.wordpress.com/2012/10/15/recursion-with-anonymous-inline-functions-in-xpath-3-0-2/)
- [Recursion with anonymous (inline) functions in XPath 3.0, Part II](https://dnovatchev.wordpress.com/2013/04/08/recursion-with-anonymous-inline-functions-in-xpath-3-0-part-ii/)