# recursive anonymous function without name

Tags: javascript

i know how to run the script by itself by using this syntax `(function(){})();`, please notice my example, there is no name assigned to that anon function. the question is, how do i make recursive function with an unamed function?

```
(function(){
    if(i < 3){
        // how to call it self without function name?       
    }
})();
```

i always give anon function a name and call itself in recursive function. but this time i want to know if it's possible to call itself without a name.

Comment: There is no other recommendable way to do this. `arguments.callee` is deprecated (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_recursion

Comment: I suppose that's why functions can have names :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternative to arguments.callee](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19214977/alternative-to-arguments-callee)

Answer (score 0):

I don't like Aleksandar's solution, simply because you're defining the function twice. Instead of writing an instance of the Y combinator you could write the Y combinator itself:

```
function y(f) {
    return function () {
        return f(y(f)).apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
```

Your anonymous function then becomes:

```
y(function (f) {
    return function (i) {
        console.log(i);
        if (i < 3) return f(i + 1);
        else return i;
    };
})(0);
```

The only difference is that you've now moved the recursion logic into the Y combinator. See the demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/d4w4a/

Anyway as Felix said, the only other solution is to use `arguments.callee` which is now deprecated. Why don't you just name your function? It's fast and it makes it easier to debug.