# Looping function with time delay in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, loops

So I'm creating a simple countdown function in AngularJS which is mean to count down to the time set in inputs. The problem is that I'm not able to loop the `$scope.countdown` function. So it only counts down once (and if I put the `$timeout($scope.countdown(), 1000);` in - it breaks entirely.) I just want it to loop every second until it reaches 0.

Here's my controller:

```
function countdownController($scope) {

  $scope.hours = 2;
  $scope.minutes = 30;

  $scope.countdown = function(){
    if($scope.minutes == 0 && $scope.hours == 0){
        alert('end!');
        return;
    }
    else{
        if($scope.minutes == 0){
            $scope.minutes = 59;
            $scope.hours--;
        }
        else{
            $scope.minutes--;
        }

    }
    $timeout($scope.countdown(), 1000); //if I remove this - the numbers display - this actually breaks that.
  }

  $scope.countdown();
}
```

Comment: I think you want to be passing the function not executing the function $timeout($scope.countdown, 1000);

Comment: @MattPileggi Can you show me where in the app to put it? I think that's what I'm missing. Thanks!

Comment: You have it in there where you put the comment about removing it.  Just change that line so that it's not invoking $scope.countdown but passing it as an object instead.

Comment: @MattPileggi I'm confused about syntax and how I can pass it as an object. Do I put it like this? `$timeout(1000){$scope.countdown()};` I'm sure that's wrong but showing you where I'm getting lost. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're looking for is [`arguments.callee`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee) :

```
$scope.countdown = function(){
    if($scope.minutes == 0 && $scope.hours == 0){
        alert('end!');
        return;
    }
    else{
        if($scope.minutes == 0){
            $scope.minutes = 59;
            $scope.hours--;
        }
        else{
            $scope.minutes--;
        }

    }
    $timeout(arguments.callee, 1000);
}
```

Or its more advised [alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361642/arguments-callee-is-deprecated-what-should-be-used-instead) :

```
function countdownController($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.hours = 0;
    $scope.minutes = 45;
    $scope.countdown = function myhandler() {
        console.log('call');
        if ($scope.minutes == 0 && $scope.hours == 0) {
            console.log('end!');
            return;
        } else {
            if ($scope.minutes == 0) {
                $scope.minutes = 59;
                $scope.hours--;
            } else {
                $scope.minutes--;
            }

        }
        $timeout(myhandler, 1000);
    }
}
```

[JsFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/floo51/HB7LU/2427/)

NB : as mentionned in the comments, don't forget to inject `$timeout` into your controller.

Comment: Thanks for this but for some reason `$timeout(myhandler, 1000);` breaks the app. The calling of it in $timeout - not the naming of he function on top. That's fine.

Comment: What does "breaks the app" actually mean ?

Comment: It works to me, updated with a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/floo51/HB7LU/2427/).

Comment: ah! I didn't include $timeout in the MyCtrl function with $scope. Now it works great. Thanks! Can you update your answer to include exactly what you have in the JSFiddle so that I can mark it as correct? Thanks!

Comment: @itamar Updated with the timeout injection

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass a function to the $timeout service. NOT the result of the function.
Try this:

```
$timeout($scope.countdown, 1000);
```

Comment: But where? As you can see I already have exactly that at the end of my $scope.countodwn function.