# There exists a use of arguments.callee with no good alternative?

Tags: javascript, strict-mode

There is a lot of fallacies about *arguments.callee* and I'm trying to understand if exists use cases where it really can't be replaced by a viable *ES5 strict mode* alternative.

In the [MDN arguments.callee](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee) documentation they point [a use of arguments.callee with no good alternative](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments/callee#A_use_of_arguments.callee_with_no_good_alternative) with the following code example below:

```
function createPerson (sIdentity) {
    var oPerson = new Function("alert(arguments.callee.identity);");
    oPerson.identity = sIdentity;
    return oPerson;
}

var john = createPerson("John Smith");

john();
```

They inclusive linked a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=725398) to show that in some cases, *argument.callee* can't be replaced by a code in conformance to *ES5 strict mode*.

But in understanding, the code they used as example can be replaced with the following *strict mode* alternative:

```
"use strict";

function createPerson(sIdentity) {
    var oPerson = function () {
        alert(oPerson.identity);
    };

    oPerson.identity = sIdentity;
    return oPerson;
}

var john = createPerson("John Smith");

john();
```

With that pointed, there really exists some algorithms where arguments.callee can't be replaced?

**BOUNTY**

To win the bounty I want the answer to contain a usage of `arguments.callee` where it will be much more obscure or impossible to use another solution.

In the MDN example, the version I wrote as an alternative doesn't change the usage of that piece of code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arguments.callee is deprecated - what should be used instead?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8361642/684229)

Comment: It is not exactly a duplicate. I'm researching if really are places where we must use `arguments.callee` and not for alternatives. Every piece of code I got I could use an alternative, but I see a lot of people arguing about the deprecation of `arguments.callee` and a I see no reason for that. To use `arguments.callee` we must walk the stack and is slow in every language I know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a use case : keep a variable for an inlined event handler (which could come from a generated/templated code) without polluting the global namespace or the DOM or risking other name collisions :

```
<button onclick="var f=arguments.callee;alert(f.i=(f.i||0)+1)">CLICK</button>
```

[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/nepejo/1/edit)

Now, let's say it's not a legitimate use. Of course there's none really legitimate or `arguments.callee` wouldn't have been axed.

Comment: Clever use, inline event handlers introduce an amount of dynamic typing and make browsers go through hoops, which is another reason not to use them.

Comment: The usage of `this` make the same result, didn't it? http://jsbin.com/bisitiru/2/edit

Comment: @SergioGarcia Yes, that's why I precised "without polluting the DOM" : using `this` adds a property to the element and you have a theoretical risk of having another similar event handler having a collision. The solution I give also lets the same function be independent of its use an for example be injected in more than one event handler : http://jsbin.com/nepejo/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

When you create a function *dynamically* (from a string), it can't "capture" any outside variables, like a normal closure does.

So, the MDN example simulates the closure by making the value accessible via `arguments.callee`. There really is no other way without changing the signature of the function.

Comment: I just put a closure to enforce the use of strict.

Comment: I updated my answer to be a little more clear ... The closure is the only thing that cannot be done by a dynamic function, hence the need for `arguments.callee`

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you misunderstand the example.
It means use the Function constructor there are not alternatives to argument.callee
That's say, the code below

```
function createPerson (sIdentity) {
    var oPerson = new Function("alert(oPerson.identity);");
    oPerson.identity = sIdentity;
    return oPerson;
}

var john = createPerson("John Smith");

john();
```

is wrong

Comment: Yes, I understand you argument, but is there a practical example where it is needed? That is what I'm looking for. Maybe a template parser and output generator or something like it. What I see is people arguing `arguments.callee` is necessary but with no strong reason why.

Comment: Just for reference, here is another demonstration of a usage of `arguments.callee`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function#Example