# How can I get a function name when it is being called?

Tags: javascript, function

I'm not sure if this is a good idea or not, but I'd like to be able to get the name of a function from within it, while it is being called. The test code I wrote below seems to work, in that it doesn't cause a name clash, but I can't get the name of the function without knowing it first.

```
function And(){
    return "test";
};
var X = {
    And:  function And(){
        return this.And.name;
    }
};
document.write(X.And());
```

Is there any way of achieving this that doesn't involve binding the context (i.e. the value of 'this') on the function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply by using this aguments.callee.name;

try this example :

```
function myFunc() 
{ 
    return arguments.callee.name; 
}
```

Note that the [arguments.callee will be depricated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361642/arguments-callee-is-deprecated-what-should-be-used-instead)

Answer (score 2):

Function.caller or arguments.callee.name

However arguments.callee() doesn't work under ES5. And Function.caller is not standard.