# Angular replacement for arguments.callee.caller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, stack-trace

I want to see an Angular stack trace when a specific function is called twice, which seems odd but is the intended behavior https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1146.

`use strict` disables `arguments.callee.caller.toString()` to print the call stack.

How can I log the caller of a named function in Angular?

Comment: Don't use strict mode? :-0 Maybe [*Arguments.callee is deprecated - what should be used instead?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361642/arguments-callee-is-deprecated-what-should-be-used-instead) helps (i.e. using named function expressions)?

Comment: I like strict mode.  Named function expressions might be promising, thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

You can produce a stack trace by doing `console.log((new Error).stack);`