# Event won't unbind

Tags: javascript

I came accross `arguments.callee.caller` which seemed to solve the problem unbinding **anonymous functions**, however I don't really understand why this works in some cases but not others.

```js
//Example 1
document.addEventListener('click', function(event){
    console.log("Example 1");
    console.log(arguments.callee.caller);
    event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(event.type, arguments.callee.caller);
});

//Example 2
document.addEventListener('click', (function(event){
  return function(){
    console.log("Example 2");
    console.log(arguments.callee.caller);
    event.currentTarget.removeEventListener(event.type, arguments.callee.caller);
  }();
}));
```

Why does `Example 2` successfully unbind, however `Example 1` doesn't when all I am doing is returning an identical anonymous function?

Comment: The function must be defined as variables. Anonymous function cannot be unbounded.

Comment: Don't use `arguments.callee`, [Arguments.callee is deprecated - what should be used instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8361642/arguments-callee-is-deprecated-what-should-be-used-instead)

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara deprecated in `strict mode` only?

Comment: @AdamAzad But Example 2 unbinds successfully and that is anonymous..

Comment: @Zze Yeah, but still causes optimization problems outside of strict mode, best to just use strict mode.

Comment: The second example returns the function pointer, thus; it can remove it. The first return null.